# How can I have an SSIS job communicate with my ASP.NET MVC site?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, ssis

When a certain thing happens in an SSIS job I have running, I need it to send internal messages out to users.

What is the easiest way to setup my ASP.NET MVC site so my SSIS service can call some action on the site and pass in a few string parameters (recipients, etc).

Should I try and use a traditional web service, or WCF service, or a normal controller action or some other method?

Thanks for your help and advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you want the site to do this? A web site is something that takes HTTP requests and gives responses. That's not what you're trying to do with the SSIS job.

Write some code in a script task, and have it executed by the SSIS job.

Comment: Can a Script Task execute code from a .NET assembly that we have in our project?

Comment: Our SSIS job sometimes will find that some data it is importing is bad.  In this case, we need to send alerts to the relevant users.  The code that handles sending out alerts/messages is in our .NET services layer of our site.  What is the best way to send some information to our services layer in this instance?

Comment: In general, one does not send alerts to web pages. If you must, then I recommend you have the SSIS job write rows to a database table, containing the username and the error text. The web site can maybe do an AJAX call to bring back any rows for the current user, and display them (like the orange bar here on SO). When the errors are dismissed, another AJAX call would delete the rows.

Comment: Yes, a script task can execute code from an assembly. You have to add a reference to it, and I think it needs to be either in the GAC or in the SSIS folder under Program Files. It can also call a web service. Do not use ASMX web services in any case - it's considered "legacy technology" by Microsoft. Use WCF instead.